# Javascript - iterating and deleting from object

Tags: javascript, object, subtraction, cumulative-sum

I have the following object

```
familyData: [
                    { man: 1, woman:10, daughter:6, son:3 },
                    { man: 4 woman:5, daughter:5, son:2 },
                    { man: 1, woman:1, daughter:1, son:1 },
                    { man: 1, woman:1, daughter:1, son:1 },
                    { man: 1, woman:1, daughter:1, son:1 },
                    ],
```

What I am trying to do is delete 1 from a each index, however the number of subtractions is user submitted.

let me explain...

If the user inserts a 2. 1 will be taken away from the first 2 indexes in the object

```
 { man: 0, woman: 9, daughter:6, son:3 },
 { man: 3 woman:4, daughter:5, son:2 },
```

If the user inserts a 4. 1 will be taken away from the first 4 indexes in the object

```
 { man: 0, woman: 9, daughter:5, son:2 },
 { man: 3 woman:4, daughter:4, son:1 },
```

I have tried a variety of for and do-while loops but cannot seem to nail it.

Comment: Please show us your attempts even if they failed.

Comment: A javascript object has no inherant "order" of properties. How do you want to distribute the items to delete a value from?

Comment: does it goes unter zero? is it applied on all elements of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var indexes = 0;
for (var i=0; i<familyData.length; ++i) {
    for (var key in familyData[i]) {
        if (++indexes < 4 && familyData[i][key]) {
            familyData[i][key]--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked this answer, mainly because it was the most straight forward. Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var input = ..... user input;

    if(input>0){
    for(var i=0; i<familyData.length; i++){
        var item = familyData[i];
        var  counter=0;
        for(prop in item)
        {
            item[prop]=item[prop]-1;
            counter++;
            if(counter==input)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution  :

```
var userValue = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < familyData.length; i++) {
      var counter = userValue;
      for (var x in familyData[i]) {
        if (!counter--) break;
        familyData[i][x]--;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed array for the order, you may use this function, which iterates over the array and over the keys of the wanted properties with a short circuit if the number is reached.

```js
function decrement(n) {
    familyData.forEach(function (a) {
        order.every(function (k, i) {
            if (i < n) {
                a[k]--;
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
}

var familyData = [{ man: 1, woman: 10, daughter: 6, son: 3 }, { man: 4, woman: 5, daughter: 5, son: 2 }, { man: 1, woman: 1, daughter: 1, son: 1 }, { man: 1, woman: 1, daughter: 1, son: 1 }, { man: 1, woman: 1, daughter: 1, son: 1 }],
    order = ['man', 'woman', 'daughter', 'son'];

decrement(3);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(familyData, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, can't for the life of me try and name that function accurately though.

```
function soAnswer(index, arr) {
  var keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);

  if (index >= keys.length || index < 0) {
    throw new Error('soAnswer was given an invalid index for given array');
  }

  keys = keys.slice(0, index);

  return arr.map(function (v) {
    keys.forEach(function (vv) {
      v[vv] -= 1;
    });

    return v;
  });
}

var outcome = soAnswer(3, familyData);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can employ Array.slice, Array.map and Array.concat

```
var num = 2
familyData.slice(0,num).map(function(members) {
   for(var name in members) {
     members[name]--
   }
   return members
}).concat(familyData.slice(num))
```

Live example: https://tonicdev.com/lipp/family